# Модуль requests

Tags: python, requests

Мне нужно получить список видео на канале https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMpoPt5DaBcscn1eLQxLCwA/videos, но проблема в том, что видео подгружаются после загрузки страницы, а модуль requests возвращает ответ сразу после загрузки, в то время как видео не успели погрузится на сайт. Можно ли как-то сделать режим ожидание в модуле requests, чтобы подгрузился блок с видео?

Мой код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMpoPt5DaBcscn1eLQxLCwA/videos',timeout=timeout)
html = BS(response.content,'html.parser')


last_video_html = html.select('ytd-grid-video-renderer')[0]
last_video_link = last_video_html.select('a[id="video-title"]')[0]['href']

input(last_video_link)
```

Comment: Можно использовать для этого selenium

Comment: это долго, для моих целей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`requests` получает статическую страницу, не обрабатывая на ней JS, который подгружает список видео. Он вам не подойдет. У вас есть два варианта:

- Использовать Selenium. Это не сильно усложнит код, но замедлит процесс парсинга. Для ускорения можно отключить подгрузку картинок и шрифтов.
- Использовать оффициальный API YouTube. Вот [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjUlmco7v2M) от Google Developers, которое описывает нужные вам методы.